# Problem using variables with feynmp

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp

I've tried the def command or pgfmathsetmacro, and the feynman diagrams are drawn as though the variable is always set to "1" regardless. The only workaround I've found is to put my feynman diagram inside a macro and use arguments as variable inputs, however this is not flexible enough to use in general (for example I would like to use random numbers to change tensions, etc, in my diagrams). The following is a complete code example, showing that the middle photon line's curvature is unaffected by changing the "\temp" variable.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{fgraphs}
\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)
      \fmftopn{t}{3}    \fmfn{plain}{t}{3}
      \fmfbottomn{b}{3} \fmfn{plain}{b}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{0.1}
      \fmf{photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=\temp}{t2,b2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant part of the definition of `vconnect` in `feynmp.mp`:

```
        elseif match_option (opt[nopt], "right"):
          if known opt[nopt]arg:
            vlist[nfrom]arc[vlist[nfrom]arc.last]lsr
              := scantokens (opt[nopt]arg);
          else:
            vlist[nfrom]arc[vlist[nfrom]arc.last]lsr := 1;
          fi
```

If you look at the generated file `simple.mp`, you'll see that `\temp` is written literally; the backslash is a no-op and `temp` is an unknown variable, so the code substitutes 1.

You can make an “expanding” version of `\fmf`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\newcommand{\efmf}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\fmf{#1}}\x
}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)
      \fmftopn{t}{3}    \fmfn{plain}{t}{3}
      \fmfbottomn{b}{3} \fmfn{plain}{b}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{0.1}
      \efmf{photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=\temp}{t2,b2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works!

Comment: On a related note, do you know if there is any way to change a variable within an fmffor loop? It's the exact same problem: if I look in the simple.mp file, there is a loop, but the variable has been replaced by '1' so it doesn't change. If I try your same solution for "fmffor", I get the following error during compilation: "Runaway loop?
vconnect("photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=-0.1",__u[(EXPR0) ETC.
! Forbidden token found while scanning the text of a for loop.
<inserted text> 
                endfor
<to be read again> 
                   end
l.67 end"

Comment: @user1247 In what part of `fmffor` should the variable go? Without an example, it's hard to guess.

Comment: Currently I have the following, where I use 'temp' in the same way as in the previous example: "  \begin{efmffor}{n}{1}{1}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\temp+1}
"

Comment: Basically all I want to do is to be able to loop over diagram vertices and change tensions. It seems that I run into the same problem you already helped me with, except regarding anything that is put within an "fmffor" loop needs to be expanded in a similar way I guess.

Comment: @user1247 Please open a new question with a proper example.

Comment: I have put a complete example (only a slight modification of your code above), at this question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484863/problem-using-variables-with-feynmp-fmffor

Comment: I have the same problem with all of the other feynmf functions: I need what you call an "expanding" version of them, so that I can pass variable tensions. I've been trying to figure out how to translate what you did for fmf to, for example, fmfcyclen, but don't really understand what is going on in your code. Can you give a general recipe?