# Problem using variables with feynmp fmffor

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484842/problem-using-variables-with-feynmp). The solution provided by egreg worked, but the same solution doesn't work when trying to update a variable within an fmffor loop. A complete example is shown below. The expected behavior is to produce two photons each bending in the opposite direction (right=+0.5, and right=-0.5), but instead \temp is always set to +0.5 in the simple.mp file.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\newcommand{\efmf}[1]{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\fmf{#1}}\x
}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)
      \fmftopn{t}{3}    \fmfn{plain}{t}{3}
      \fmfbottomn{b}{3} \fmfn{plain}{b}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{-1.5}
      \begin{fmffor}{n}{1}{1}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\temp+1}
        \efmf{photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=\temp}{t2,b2}
      \end{fmffor}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Here is another complete example that includes the needed functionality of fmffor (it should display the photon loop bent to the left on the left, and to the right on the right):

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgf}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\efmf}{mm}
 {
  \xfmf_fmf:xn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xfmf_fmf:nn { \fmf{#1}{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xfmf_fmf:nn { x }
\NewDocumentCommand{\fmfcycle}{mmmm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__xfmf_fmfcycle:n { #4 }
  \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } \__xfmf_fmfcycle:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)
      \fmftopn{t}{3}    \fmfn{plain}{t}{3}
      \fmfbottomn{b}{3} \fmfn{plain}{b}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{-2}
      \begin{fmffor}{n}{1}{1}{3}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\temp+1}
        \efmf{photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=\temp/5}{t[n],b[n]}
      \end{fmffor}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If `\temp` is -0.5, then `\temp+1` is 0.5. What's the problem? You're simply doing the `vconnect` operation twice with the same data.

Comment: Note that `fmffor` doesn't execute the body multiple times, but only writes code for a Metapost loop.

Comment: I edited with your suggested modification, but I still have the same problem with the updated code. Note that the temp variable should be -0.5 and +0.5. There should be two photon loops, not one, because the \temp variable should be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fmffor` environment doesn't execute the body multiple times.

Here I propose a different loop macro. The first three arguments are the initial point, the step and the final point. You refer to the current value during the loop as `#1` in the fourth argument.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\efmf}{mm}
 {
  \xfmf_fmf:xn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xfmf_fmf:nn { \fmf{#1}{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xfmf_fmf:nn { x }
\NewDocumentCommand{\fmfcycle}{mmmm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__xfmf_fmfcycle:n { #4 }
  \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } \__xfmf_fmfcycle:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)
      \fmftopn{t}{3}    \fmfn{plain}{t}{3}
      \fmfbottomn{b}{3} \fmfn{plain}{b}{3}
      \fmfcycle{0}{1}{1}{
        \efmf{photon, foreground=blue, tension=0.1, right=-0.5+#1}{t2,b2}
      }
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Like in my previous code I removed the `pdftex` option for `graphicx` and the useless `\begin{fmffile}{fgraphs}` and the matching `\end{fmffile}` lines.

Comment: OK, this looks like you and I are now on the same page. Thanks a bunch. I will test it and get back to you.

Comment: @user1247 I fixed the code to have -0.5 and 0.5.

Comment: How would this work if it was already inside a macro that was using the "#1"?

Comment: Looking more deeply at this -- I don't think this works as a general solution, because it does not reproduce the functionality of "fmffor". I can provide a more detailed example if necessary. For fmffor, the loop variable is used to index vertices, as in "v[n]", which is necessary functionality for it to be useful. Or maybe I don't understand your solution.

Comment: I've added another example that I don't think your solution works with

Comment: OK, sorry, I think it does work (as long as I take care of the "n" increment myself that fmffor normally takes care of), however I'm still confused about the role of the #1 what happens when there is already a "#1" argument being used